# How can I write a large multidimensional array to an HDF5 file in parts?

Tags: c#, .net, multidimensional-array, hdf5

I'm using HDF5DotNet in C# and I have a very large array (several GB) that I want to write to an HDF5 file. It's too big to store the whole thing in memory, so I'm generating regions of it at a time and want to write them out, but still have it look like one big array when it's read back out. I know this is possible with HDF5 but the documentation for the .NET API is somewhat sparse.

I wrote some short example code with a 5 x 3 array filled with values 1..15:

```
const int ROWS = 5;
const int COLS = 3;

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    WriteWholeArray();
    WriteArrayByRows();
    ushort[,] array = ReadWholeArray();
}

static void WriteWholeArray()
{
    H5FileId h5 = H5F.create(Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), "test.h5"), H5F.CreateMode.ACC_TRUNC);
    H5DataSpaceId dsi = H5S.create_simple(2, new long[] { ROWS, COLS });
    H5DataSetId dataset = H5D.create(h5, "array", new H5DataTypeId(H5T.H5Type.NATIVE_USHORT), dsi);
    ushort[,] array = new ushort[ROWS, COLS];
    ushort value = 1;
    for(int i = 0; i < array.GetLength(0); i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < array.GetLength(1); j++)
        {
            array[i, j] = value++;
        }
    }
    H5D.write<ushort>(dataset, new H5DataTypeId(H5T.H5Type.NATIVE_USHORT), new H5Array<ushort>(array));
    H5D.close(dataset);
    H5F.close(h5);
}

static void WriteArrayByRows()
{
    H5FileId h5 = H5F.create(Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), "test.h5"), H5F.CreateMode.ACC_TRUNC);
    H5DataSpaceId dsi = H5S.create_simple(2, new long[] { ROWS, COLS });
    H5DataSetId dataset = H5D.create(h5, "array", new H5DataTypeId(H5T.H5Type.NATIVE_USHORT), dsi);
    ushort[,] array = new ushort[ROWS, COLS];
    ushort value = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < array.GetLength(0); i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < array.GetLength(1); j++)
        {
            array[i, j] = value++;
        }
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < array.GetLength(0); i++)
    {
        H5S.selectHyperslab(dsi, H5S.SelectOperator.SET, new long[] { i, 0 }, new long[] { 1, array.GetLength(1) });
        ushort[,] row = new ushort[1, array.GetLength(1)];
        for(int j = 0; j < array.GetLength(1); j++)
        {
            row[0, j] = array[i, j];
        }
        H5D.write<ushort>(dataset, new H5DataTypeId(H5T.H5Type.NATIVE_USHORT), new H5Array<ushort>(row));
    }
    H5D.close(dataset);
    H5F.close(h5);
}

static ushort[,] ReadWholeArray()
{
    H5FileId h5 = H5F.open(Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), "test.h5"), H5F.OpenMode.ACC_RDONLY);
    ushort[,] array = new ushort[ROWS, COLS];
    H5Array<ushort> h5_array = new H5Array<ushort>(array);
    H5DataSetId dataset = H5D.open(h5, "array");
    H5D.read<ushort>(dataset, new H5DataTypeId(H5T.H5Type.NATIVE_USHORT), h5_array);
    H5D.close(dataset);
    H5F.close(h5);
    return (array);
}
```

When I write the whole array at once, it reads back in fine. When I try to write by rows, the array I read back in has some correct values (in the wrong elements), some zeroes, and some crazy values (e.g. 43440). Can somebody show me how to do this correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. Apparently when you write hyperslabs of an array you need a second dataspace corresponding to the array in memory that you are writing. Here is the corrected function:

```
static void WriteArrayByRows()
{
    H5FileId h5 = H5F.create(Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), "test.h5"), H5F.CreateMode.ACC_TRUNC);
    H5DataSpaceId dsi = H5S.create_simple(2, new long[] { ROWS, COLS });
    H5DataSetId dataset = H5D.create(h5, "array", new H5DataTypeId(H5T.H5Type.NATIVE_USHORT), dsi);
    ushort[,] array = new ushort[ROWS, COLS];
    ushort value = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < array.GetLength(0); i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < array.GetLength(1); j++)
        {
            array[i, j] = value++;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < array.GetLength(0); i++)
    {
        H5S.selectHyperslab(dsi, H5S.SelectOperator.SET, new long[] { i, 0 }, new long[] { 1, array.GetLength(1) });
        H5DataSpaceId dsi2 = H5S.create_simple(2, new long[] { 1, array.GetLength(1) });  // added
        ushort[,] row = new ushort[1, array.GetLength(1)];
        for (int j = 0; j < array.GetLength(1); j++)
        {
            row[0, j] = array[i, j];
        }
        H5PropertyListId pli = new H5PropertyListId(H5P.Template.DEFAULT);  // added
        H5D.write<ushort>(dataset, new H5DataTypeId(H5T.H5Type.NATIVE_USHORT), dsi2, dsi, pli, new H5Array<ushort>(row));  // modified
    }
    H5D.close(dataset);
    H5F.close(h5);
}
```

I also found chunking to be very useful for getting decent performance writing my large array, here is an example of that:

```
H5PropertyListId pli = H5P.create(H5P.PropertyListClass.DATASET_CREATE);  // added
H5P.setChunk(pli, new long[] { 1, COLS });  // added
H5DataSetId dataset = H5D.create(h5, "array", new H5DataTypeId(H5T.H5Type.NATIVE_USHORT), dsi, H5P.create(H5P.PropertyListClass.LINK_CREATE), pli, H5P.create(H5P.PropertyListClass.DATASET_ACCESS));  // modified
```

Comment: This is also the only example of reading a multi-dim dataset in HFD5DotNet that I could find anywhere.